# Pass variables between different .js files; one is inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have 2 .js files in the html document like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/2.js"></script>
```

That document also have an iframe. I have 2 .js in the iframe aswell:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/3.js"></script>
```

So 2.js is in both documents. My plan was to make that to connect them.
I can not put 3.js in both documents because it will mess up stuff.

1.js got a variable. I want to use that variable in 3.js. But i can't figure out how to pass a variable from 1.js to 3.js.
Is this even possible?

*The variable is declared in 1.js.

Comment: What do you mean by "pass". You mean global scope, from-to a function. Just by including 1 file after the other makes all global scope variables visible to the next file.

Comment: From the code in the `<iframe>`, a variable in the parent window can be accessed as `window.parent.someVariable`

Comment: `2.js` is not the same element in the 2 pages, what you are doing is instanciate one in the main HTML and on other in the iframe, so you won't connect them in this way

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can not "pass" variables through file references. You would need to add code to pass data from the parent frame to the iframe.

If the variable is global it is

```
//from the iframe
var theVariable = window.parent.yourVaraibleName;

//from the parent
var theVariable = document.getElementById("iframeId").contentWindow.yourVaraibleName;
```

Comment: so simple :) is there a way to simply do the opposite to? From 3.js in the iframe to 1.js

Answer (score 3):

Why not using jQuery cookies to pass the variables? Even within the multiple pages. Once you pass the variable you can destroy the cookie.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass variables from one js file to the other
Javascript variables are `stateless` so they wont be retained.
If you are using .Net then you can make use of Session variables to solve this purpose.
If you use MVC you can go for viewbag or viewdata. 
If its a must then declare some variable in the homepage, then assign the value to be passed to the variable in home page and then call the function in 3.js passing this parameter.

Comment: but that is useless if the variables are dynamic and change on the page. You would have to refresh the age to get the new values from the server.

Comment: No that wont be needed if you are making use of Session variables !!
Value of session variables will be retained across the entire application and can be accessed from any page

Comment: But if the variable is updated on the client, there is no way the other page would be able to get that variable.

Answer (score 1):

jus create a global variable, don't use var keyword

```
myGlobal = "probably not a good idea but still";
```