# How can i pass a variable from js file to another using ajax jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have 2 js files and i want to pass 2 variables from file1.js to file2.js. What i have done until now is to send these 2 variables from file1.js in a 3rd file file3.php with ajax using this:

```
$('#replace').click(function(){
    var replacement = cur;
    var replacement2 = cur2;
      $.ajax({
      url: DOMAIN_NAME+"file3.php",
      type: "post",
      data: {replacement: replacement, replacement2 : replacement2},
      success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
      },
      error:function(){
        alert('Something Went Wrong');
      },
    });
  });
```

In my file3.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['replacement']) && isset($_POST['replacement2']){
$a =  $_POST['replacement'];
$b = $_POST['replacement2'];
}
<input type="hidden" id="af" value="<?=$a;?>">
<input type="hidden" id="bf" value="<?=$b;?>">
```

In my File2.js:

```
var a = $('#af').val();
var b = $('#bf').val();
```

i can see that in the network the ajax passes the variable with a status 200 OK but in the php file my variables doesn't pass. So the file2.js can't get the values. What i am doing wrong??

Comment: take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172634/pass-variables-between-different-js-files

Comment: i think this issue doesn't help me :/

Comment: you can also try with jquery cookie https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have this simple form:

```
<form id="my_form">
    <input type="text" name="a_field" id="a_field">
    <input type="text" name="b_field" id="b_field">
    <button id="submit_form">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The jquery script file (#1) for this form can be named "script1.js" and can look like that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit_form').on('click').function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = $('#my_form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'my_ajax.php',
            data: formData
        });
    });
});
```

Notice that I serialized the form to be quicker... (If you want you can specify which variables you want to pass to ajax)

Here is an example of my_ajax.php:

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["a_var"])){unset($_SESSION["a_var"]);}
if(isset($_SESSION["b_var"])){unset($_SESSION["b_var"]);}

if(isset($_POST["a_field"])){$a_field=htmlspecialchars($_POST["a_field"]);}else{$a_field=""; exit();}

if(isset($_POST["b_field"])){$b_field=htmlspecialchars($_POST["b_field"]);}else{$b_field=""; exit();}

$_SESSION["a_var"] = $a_field;
$_SESSION["b_var"] = $b_field;

?>
```

With the above file, we created two php sessions based to the input-field values that we acquired from our html form.

Now the "tricky" part:

Your SECOND js file (#2) must be given an extension .php and NOT .js

It will however execute any javascript code if of course that code is enclosed in "script" tags

Let's name that file "script2.js.php" -which can be like that:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["a_var"])){$value_a = $_SESSION["a_var"];}else{$value_a="";}
if(isset($_SESSION["b_var"])){$value_b = $_SESSION["b_var"];}else{$value_b="";}
?>
<script>/*...include jquery here (if necessary)...*/</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    //jquery is NOT necessary for my example
    //I just included it in case you need to do other tasks...

    var valueA = '<?php echo $value_a; ?>';
    var valueB = '<?php echo $value_b; ?>';

    //Now you can do anything with these values... For example, you could alert them:
    alert('Value A: '+valueA+' - Value B: '+valueB);
});
</script>
```

One last thing:

While to include a js file to your html page you do:

```
<script src="http://www.example.com/scripts/yourscript.js"></script>
```

To include the "js.php" file you must do it by using the php "include" function:

This is how I would suggest to pass variables from one js file to another by using php sessions!

My example is quite "basic" and could take a lot of "polishing" work regarding functionality and security... But should give you an idea as of how to start...

Hope that helps you and/or others...