# how to pass a string from one .js file to another .js file

Tags: javascript, youtube

I have a javascript file where I declare a variable naming ID, and after some methods its generates a string like every video of youtube has its own id. Now I want to pass it to another java script file where I want to execute it.

`a.setAttribute('href', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + id);`

That is the parameter naming id, and now I want to pass it to another JS file, that is following:

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()

 {
        player = new YT.Player('player', 

{

 height: '390',

width: '640',

      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
```

Now i want to replace the video ID that is 'M7lc1UVf-VE' with the first one javascript file parameter naming id.
How can i do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass variables between different .js files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172634/pass-variables-between-different-js-files)

Comment: I've tried my best to improve this question, but it was hard for even me to understand. Please read through this question again, and provide a meaningful edit to try and clarify your question.

Comment: i am making a youtube embedd search, where one js file is creating a yotube Id , which is a video and i want to play that video on that tab, like https://yout.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global variable (it not always safe though) and save it there. Then it will be accessible from any other js file. 
Another way is to store it to local storage and get it from there.

It isn't safe to create a global variable because in a project that work more than one developers there is a possibility to create or change the same variable at different points of the code.

To create a global variable you can type `var str = 'foo';` outside any function of you code (and after `$('document').ready()`).

To save to local storage is achieved by typing something like `localStorage.setItem("str", "foo");`
and to get the value 
`localStorage.getItem("str");

Comment: Why isn't it safe? How does one create a global variable? Provide some examples, and help provide high quality answers.

Comment: I isn't safe because in a project that work more than one developers there is a possibility to create or change the same variable at different points of the code. 
To create a global variable you can type var str = 'foo'; outside any function of you code (and after $('document').ready()).

Comment: Edit your answer, and include that info

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are defined on the window object, at thus are available in different files. For example:

`file1.js:`
    var str = "foo"

`file2.js:`
    console.log(str)

should work just fine, so long as you're pulling in the scripts in the right order in the html:

```
<script src="file1.js"></script>
<script src="file2.js"></script>
```

However, this isn't really the best way to do it. You would be better off using something like Gulp or Grunt to take all the JS files in your project and concatenate them, and then serve them up as a single file. Better still would be to use Webpack with Babel, and then you can also use the new ES6 `import` and `export` statements (though that said, webpack can be a real bear to configure).